# On the polynomials $x^n-x-1$ with $n>1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, galois-groups

In 1956, E. S. Selmer proved in a paper [Math. Scand. 4 (1956), 287-302] that for any integer $n>1$ the polynomial $x^n-x-1$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers.

**Question.** Is it true that for any integer $n>1$ the polynomial $x^n-x-1$ is irreducible modulo some prime $p<n(n+3)/2$?

My computation supports a positive answer to this question, but I'm unable to prove this.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: From your data so far, how sharp is the bound on $p$?

Comment: Selmer's proof does not even imply that such a prime $p$ exists.

Comment: How far have you computed up to?

Comment: Let $a(n)$ be the least prime $p$ such that $x^n-x-1$ is irreducible modulo $p$. The values of $a(2),\ldots,a(500)$ are available from http://oeis.org/A223934. For example, $a(20)=229<20(20+3)/2=230$.

Comment: There are similar (and simpler) looking irreducible polynomials which are reducible modulo **every** prime. For example, $x^4+1$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77155/irreducible-polynomial-which-is-reducible-modulo-every-prime

Comment: Note that when $n$ itself is prime, the polynomial $x^{n}-x-1$ is irreducible (mod $n$). For if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{n}-x-1$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{n}$, then $\alpha^{n^{k}} = \alpha + k $ for $ 1 \leq k \leq n$, so that $k = n$ is the smallest positive value of $k$ for which $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{n^{k}} - x.$ Hence $\alpha$ is not a root of any polynomial of degree less than $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_{n}[x].$

Comment: Conditional on the generalized Riemann hypothesis, we should have some bound of the form $O(n \log (n))$ by the Chebotarev density theorem argument. It is in principle possible to make this effective, and then the equality could potentially be checked by computer for small $n$. This relies on the fact that the Galois group is $S_n$, which is listed as a conjecture by OEIS but is known. See e.g. The Galois Groups of the Polynomials  $X^n + aX^l +b$ by Hiroyuki Osada. (This answers dodd's objection that such a prime may not exist - it must, unconditionally, by Chebotarev.)

Comment: Sorry, that was silly, the GRH bound is more like $O( 4^n n^2 \log (n)^2)$ which is not nearly enough for your purposes.

Comment: Will, thank you for your helpful comments.